# Verify identity $\frac{\sin(t+h)-\sin(t)}{h}$ = $\cos(t)$ $\frac{\sin(h)}{h}$ + $\sin(t)$ $\frac{\cos(h)-1}{h}$

Tags: trigonometry

I've been asked to verify the following identity and I don't know how to do it.

$\frac{\sin(t+h)-\sin(t)}{h}$ =$ \cos(t)$ $\frac{\sin(h)}{h}$ + $\sin(t)$ $\frac{\cos(h)-1}{h}$

When I try I get:

$\frac{\sin(t+h)-\sin(t)}{h}$ = $\frac{\sin(t)\cos(h)+\cos(t)\sin(h)-\sin(t)}{h}$

I've then seen some things on the internet showing that:

$\sin(t)\cos(h)-\sin(t) = \sin(t)\cos(h-1)$

This could be a next step but no one ever explains how this identity works. This identity doesn't show up when I look up identities in general and the ones that do show up tell you the identity for different combinations of $\cos(a)$ and $\sin(b)$, for example the double-angle identity or sum-to-product identity.  So if you can shed some light on this one as well it would be appreciated.

Comment: It's the addition formula for the sine function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities

Comment: This is not the answer to your question, but a better way to express the relation to calculate the limit

using http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

$$\sin(t+h)-\sin t=2\sin\dfrac{t+h-t}2\cos\dfrac{t+h+t}2$$

Comment: @Angina Seng.  Thank you for responding.  I still don't get it.  The addition formula for sin is sin(a+b) = sin(a)cos(b)+cos(a)sin(b).  So maybe you mean the subtraction of sin inputs which is sin(a-b) = sin(a)cos(b)-cos(a)sin(b).  So in my case if I have sin(t)cos(h) - sin(t) I don't see how this fits with sin(a)cos(b)-cos(a)sin(b) because i have sin(a) on one side of the subtraction sine and sin(b) on the other side.  not sin(a)cos(b)-sin(a).  What I'm I getting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the correct answer, just need one more step to break the terms up as requested. Namely:
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin(t+h)-\sin(t)}{h} &= \frac{\sin(t)\cos(h)+\cos(t)\sin(h)-\sin(t)}{h} \\
&= \frac{\sin(h)\cos(t)+\sin(t)(\cos(h)-1)}{h} \\
&= \cos(t)\cdot\frac{\sin(h)}h+\sin(t)\cdot\frac{\cos(h)-1}{h}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I still don't see how sin(t)cos(h)-sin(t) is equal to sin(t)(cos(h)-1). Is this something that can be broken down or is it already just something you accept?  Is there a name for this identity?

Comment: It's a special case of $ab-a=a(b-1)$, which is a special case of the *distributive law*.

Comment: @Angina Seng AH!  THATS IT!  THANK YOU!!!

Comment: I can also see the error in my thinking now.  i was confusing cos(h)-1 with cos(h-1).  This had me all sorts of messed up. Thanks everyone!